# Chrome vs Firefox Rendering Issues

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

I'm having issues rending my website using browsers such as Chrome, Safari, etc. The rendering on Firefox and newer editions of IE are acceptable. I will explain the issues I'm running into.

First issue I found is when inspecting the page (http://devildogusainc.org) on Chrome. I receive the following console messages:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://devildogusainc.org/assets/js/head.min.js.map
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.devildogusainc.org/dev/img-gallery2/third.party/hammer.js/hammer.min.map
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://devildogusainc.org/assets/css/bootstrap.css.map
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://devildogusainc.org/assets/css/bootstrap.css.map
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://devildogusainc.org/assets/js/head.min.js.map
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.devildogusainc.org/dev/img-gallery2/third.party/hammer.js/hammer.min.map
```

I'm not sure why it does this, because none of my files end with .map

My next issue is found within the expandable drown down boxes. An issue with the staff page, or wherever they're contained (index, sponsors, and supporters). The boxes on Chrome have pointers that adjust depending on their orientation, such as when not expanded they appear horizontally ( -> ) and when expanded they appear to point downward toward the content. I'll post the css for the summary css container.

```
summary {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-ms-box-sizing: border-box;
-o-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
position: relative;
border-left: 10px solid #00698c;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #004d66;
cursor: pointer;
display: block;
font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
font-weight: 900;
font-size: 22px;
text-align: center;
height: auto;
width: 350px;
margin: 0;
padding: 1.625rem;
position: relative;
background: #0099cc;
color: #fff;
}
```

These are my main issues, one's that have stumped me for well over a week. Hopefully I can find a solution from the Stackoverflow community.

Thanks.

Comment: I do not see the 404 errors w/ Chrome, though I do see `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null` which is likely going to cause various issues w/ your page.

Comment: I don't believe it has anything to do with the remainder of the page. The error is a result of the Google Map API integration to the contact page. I could be wrong, but I'm pretty confident.

Answer (score 1):

For your first problem:

This isn't a problem in the first place but a feature in Chrome DevTools known as Source Maps. Source Maps are used for debugging of compressed or compiled Javascript and CSS code so that you do not require the actual uncompressed and uncompiled code. This very useful when Javascript is being compiled from other languages like Coffee Script or even Java (in case of GWT).

Check out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-xJl22Kvgjg

If you don't want to see those errors, either include the source maps for the corresponding files or disable the feature in Chrome DevTools Settings. They go by the name "Enable Javascript source maps" and "Enable CSS source maps" under "General -> Sources"

Hope this helps. :)